# Multiple Projects, Multiple languages, Same authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, postgresql, authentication

So I have multiple projects that I want to use a common core set of tables in a Postgres database to map an authentication scheme between them with. Things like a 'user' 'account' 'group' or other related user information is stored in these tables. The projects I have currently are a nodejs (multiple devices) and a Ruby web app (planning on multiple devices later on) and we could have a Django or another node project in the future as well. Is there an efficient, cost effective way to do this that would be scalable and reliable? I was thinking about using an s3 instance with a Postgres database hosted on it and pointing all my authentication from my multiple apps to that database but I wanted to see if others had thought about this problem as well.

Comment: Avoid using the table name `user`, you'll have to quote it everywhere like `"user"` because there's a built-in pseudo-function by that name and it's a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

First, please don't attempt to host postgres in S3.. I believe you may have meant EC2 with an EBS volume (which is really on s3). From an ease of use standpoint (particularly when considering ongoing maintenance), hosting any postgres instance on Amazon's RDS product is truly a pleasure. Without going into all the details of that product, I'll simply state that you can set up high availability (failover), backups, upgrades, and monitoring with just a few clicks.

That being said, RDS is not the cheapest solution, but the cost is not exorbitant either, depending on your load and number of simultaneous connections.

If all this database is going to do is authenticate people and then disconnect-- that very well will be overkill and will be a waste of resources. However, if you're housing a fairly complex set of permissions  and other user data, it'll likely be a fairly straightforward solution.

Depending on your budget and requirements, you may benefit from running pgPool on your app server somewhere to pool the connections-- but I wouldn't start out using pgPool unless you need it.